# ons-popover 2.0 - invoke via pure javascript and not angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca, onsen-ui2

I am trying to mimic this but using Onsen 2.0 without AngularJS:

http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/zxGEza?editors=1010

```
var app = ons.bootstrap();

app.controller('DropdownController', function($scope) {
  ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });
});
```

In short, how can you trigger a popover in JS and not use the ons.bootstrap() as this will result in an error due to AngularJS not being included?

My page calling looks like:

```
<div class="right">
   <ons-toolbar-button onclick="????">
   <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" style="font-size: 32px; width: 1em;"></ons-icon>
   </ons-toolbar-button>
</div>

<ons-template id="popover.html">
      <ons-popover direction="down" cancelable>
        <ons-list>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Option 1</ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Option 2</ons-list-item>
          <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">Option 3</ons-list-item>
        </ons-list>
      </ons-popover>
    </ons-template>
```

Comment: Thank you Fran Dios! That worked wonders.  Can't believe I missed that.  Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ons.bootstrap` is only needed for AngularJS. If you don't include AngularJS you can omit it without troubles. And you use the popover in the same way but without controllers, of course:

```
var popover;

ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(element) {
  popover = element;
});

function show(id) {
  popover.show(id);
};
```

Check it here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/LGQwVM